# How to Handle Pause Event in SAPI Engine

Tags: sapi

I currently have a SAPI voice implemented which works fine. I would like to know how do I handle Pause event in the engine when the application calls ISpVoice->Pause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As near as I can tell, `ISpVoice::Pause` is implemented entirely in the SAPI layer and doesn't make any engine calls.

Comment: Currently I write the whole audio buffer with multiple words, may be I need to write individual words, am not sure if that's the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to understand exactly what your end goal is, but I think I'll take a stab at answering this.

For voices, pause does the following according to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms719596%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

**ISpVoice::Pause** *pauses the voice at the nearest alert boundary and closes the output device, allowing access to pending speak requests from other voices.*

Assuming you've used the speak call with SPF_AYSNC, you might also have to also set event interests and alert boundaries as seen [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee125632%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Where the example shows handling bookmark alert boundaries

```
'Create a Normal Priority voice - male
Set objHIM = New SpVoice
Set objHIM.Voice = objHIM.GetVoices("gender=male").Item(0)

objHER.Speak "the priority of this voice is S V P alert"
objHIM.Speak "the priority of this voice is S V P normal"

objHIM.EventInterests = SVEBookmark     'Receive bookmark events only
objHIM.AlertBoundary = SVEPhoneme       'Let alert voices interrupt words

'Normal voice speaks text which generates events.

strSpeak = "This is text  that contains bookmarks " _
            & "for the  purpose of generating events."

objHIM.Speak strSpeak, SVSFIsXML + SVSFlagsAsync
```

Comment: This is from Application's perspective, but I would like to know how do I handle it in the engine if the pause event is triggered from the application. For example, I call ISpTTSEngineSite::GetActions in the engine to get rate, volume changes etc. And similarly for knowing application's interest I call ISpTTSEngineSite::GetEventInterest. What I don't understand is how to get/check if the pause event is triggered and steps to handle them in the engine side.